# Dual screen metro app

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I've read that in Windows 8 Metro UI runs only on single screen at a time. If you have 2 displays Metro will run on one of them and desktop environment in the other.

Is it possible to create a Metro app utilizing two screens? The first display would contain a control interface and the 2nd display would output full screen video?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. It isn't possible. Windows Metro UI always runs on primary display and always runs in full screen and no way to put full screen app on two displays.

You can check for details [in this product guide](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=238697) on 44th page.

You can use [snap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465371.aspx) for showing two metro apps on one screen but no way two show one app on two or more screens.